# nullptr_t not defined on g++ 4.9.2

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am using C++ Rest SDK on a project in linux comipled with g++ 4.9.2 with the -std=c++11 flag set.

Internaly C++ Rest SDK checks if nullptr exists like that:

```
#if defined nullptr_t
#define NEEDS_NULLPTR_DEFINED 0
#else
#define NEEDS_NULLPTR_DEFINED 1
#endif
#if NEEDS_NULLPTR_DEFINED
#define nullptr NULL
#endif
```

This check fail on my machine leading nullptr to be defined as NULL which breaks the compilation afterwards. I am not quite sure if g++ or C++ Rest SDK is to blame for that problem.

Do you have any idea on why this nullptr_t check fails with g++ 4.9.2 and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I submitted an issue to C++ REST SDK: https://casablanca.codeplex.com/workitem/340

Comment: You should test on C++ being C++11 or some earlier version !

Comment: Try: `#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >= 201103L)` instead.

Comment: Thank you but sadly this code is not mine, it is from the C++ REST SDK and fixing it breaks the compilation of the library. I submitted an issue.

Comment: The build break appears to be due to a bug in `boost::function`; it doesn't handle `nullptr` correctly. I submitted https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10981

Answer (score 7):

`nullptr_t` is not defined by the preprocessor, so having the preprocessor check for it won't work.  `nullptr` is defined in `g++-4.9.2` with `-std=c++11`, which a quick test program can verify.

```
    int main() {
      std::nullptr_t i = nullptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you misunderstand what `#ifdef` tests for. Specifically

```
#if defined identifier
```

will (from §16.1, emphasis mine):

> evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a **macro name** (that is, if it is predefined or if it
>   has been the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef` directive with the
>   same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

It only can check for if the identifier is defined by `#define`. But `std::nullptr_t` isn't a a macro name - it's a typedef. Specifically (§18.2/9):

> `nullptr_t` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>     typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
> }
> ```

In a similar vein, the following program won't print anything:

```
int main() {
    #ifdef int
    std::cout << "int is defined" << std::endl;
    #endif
}
```

The test you want instead is:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    // C++11
#else
    // not C++11
#endif
```

From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html):

> `__cplusplus`
>   This macro is defined when the C++ compiler is in use. You can use `__cplusplus` to test whether a header is compiled by a C compiler or a C++ compiler. This macro is similar to `__STDC_VERSION__`, in that it expands to a version number. Depending on the language standard selected, the value of the macro is `199711L`, as mandated by the 1998 C++ standard; `201103L`, per the 2011 C++ standard; an unspecified value strictly larger than `201103L` for the experimental languages enabled by `-std=c++1y` and `-std=gnu++1y`.